# Flutter: Stream Builder does not work correctly when it is fed with observable1.mergeWith([observable2])

Tags: dart, flutter, reactivex

I want to merge two Observables or Streams to be used as a streamed input for A Stream Builder to build build out a listview out of those Streamed objects . .

I tried

```
observable1.mergeWith([observable2])
```

this but the lsit view only showed observable 2. 
if i chain another observable like `observable1.mergeWith([observable2]).mergewith([observable3]) Or observable1.mergeWith([observable2,observable3])`

this only showed me obervable3.

I tried concatwith , combinelatest2 but nothing worked. Any Solution to this.

I tried this too

```
Observable.combineLatest2(
                         Observable1, Observable2, (a, b) {
                         print("lengtsdfsdf"+a.length);
                        print("lengtsdfsdf"+b.length);
                        return List.from(a)..addAll(b);
                       }); // Here the Obsevables are of type Observable<List<obj>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what the problem here is that each stream emits an event when the response from Firebase arrives, where the data is a collection of entries.

One event example is the result from `StreamA` is `['a', 'b', 'c']` and
one event from `StreamB` is `['e', 'f', 'g']`.

What you seem to expect from `Observable.merge()` is

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
```

but actually it emits 2 events.
First

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and then

```
['e', 'f', 'g'].
```

`Flutter/StreamBuilder` first causes the data from the first event to render, then, when the 2nd event arrives at the widget, it is rebuilt with the data from the 2nd event.

The `Observable.scan` operator allows you to combine data from multiple events into a single event.